# IOS application that uses Facebook SDK, which options should be selected on iTunes Connect IDFA?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store-connect, idfa

My iOS Application is using Facebook SDK

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:FACEBOOK_ID];

[FBAppEvents activateApp];
```

So Which options should be selected on iTunes Connect?

Also Should I Check

> Limit Ad Tracking Settings

Thanks for your answers,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Facebook` uses the `IDFA` to attribute installs. So you should check the second checkbox.

In case you also show ads, then you should check the first box too.

Good luck with your submission!

Comment: thank you for your answer then what about the Limit Ad Tracking settings in iOS?

Comment: Yes, you should mark that. It is a statement of good faith. You are stating that you're not going to use the IDFA data for "bad" purposes.